# Cannot view default site from local network

Tags: 12.04, apache2, webserver

Not sure what i have done but now when I put in my servers IP address it is no longer loading the default index.html that comes with it.

I think I did this when trying to learn how to add multiple sites.

I can access my webmin page via the port, but I cannot access that and the phpmyadmin,

I have checked that the default site is in the sites-enabled, I have also check the file to make sure the default directory is correct.

Can anybody suggest where I should look and check ?

Comment: just rebooted the server and saw this as it was loading up
`[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no virtual hosts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have modified the virtual hosts incorrectly. You can try removing all files from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` directory, and temporarily create a new file `default.conf` (Ubuntu 13.10 onwards `.conf` has to be suffixed in the name) and put the following in there

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Restart apache and then see if it works. If it does, then slowly one by one try implementing the virtual hosts. Use `sites-available` instead of `sites-enabled` to keep your configuration as a practice, and enable only the needed ones through `a2ensite`.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, unfourtunalty i tried that and it didnt work. i used a2dissite to remove the linked sites in sites-enabled, created a file called default.conf (with above code) then went to restart server and got this 

`webadmin@webserver:/etc/apache2$ sudo service apache2 reload                    apache2: Syntax error on line 237 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default2: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!`

Comment: ignore that code ^^ i forgot to sudo a2dissite, it starts up correctly now, however i am still not unable to view the default "it works" site

Comment: after i had done all that and restarted my server, it some how started running and loaded the site so i a2ensite for the site i want and although it just show the files, its loading up, thanks for helping me debug my error it must have been in the default file i will have to look at it later